# undefined variable in PHP function

Tags: php, undefined

I used a ins function to insert in data base and i create a object for mysqli.The mysqli object shows error of undefined variable.and my code was

```
<?php
include "config.php";
global $mysqli;
 $mysqli = &new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db);
function ins($name)
{
 $stmt=$mysqli->prepare("insert into table demo values(?)");
 $stmt->bind_param("s",$name);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->close();
}
ins("krishna");
?>
```

Here the server name ,user name password and db name are stored in config.php

Comment: if you can echo these variables in that file, just above the line this means they are in the scope

Comment: you should add the exact, full error message with the line number where it occurs

Comment: You need to define the global $mysqli inside your function.